# Why does the .NET CLR not inline this properly?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

I ran into less than ideal inlining behavior of the .NET JIT compiler.  The following code is stripped of its context, but it demonstrates the problem:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace HashTest
{
    public class Hasher
    {
        private const int hashSize = sizeof(ulong) * 8;
        public int SmallestMatch;
        public int Offset;
        public void Hash_Inline(ref ulong hash, byte[] data, int curIndex)
        {
            hash = (hash << 1) | (hash >> (hashSize - 1));
            hash ^= data[curIndex];
            if (curIndex < SmallestMatch)
            {
                ulong value = data[curIndex - SmallestMatch];
                value = (value << Offset) | (value >> (hashSize - Offset));
                hash ^= value;
            }
        }
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        private void RotateLeft(ref ulong hash, int by)
        {
            hash = (hash << by) | (hash >> (hashSize - by));
        }
        public void Hash_FunctionCall(ref ulong hash, byte[] data, int curIndex)
        {
            RotateLeft(ref hash, curIndex);
            hash ^= data[curIndex];
            if (curIndex < SmallestMatch)
            {
                ulong value = data[curIndex - SmallestMatch];
                RotateLeft(ref value, Offset);
                hash ^= value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the assembly code it generates at runtime with a Release build (just the first line of the function, up to the xor on the second line of each function):

```
net472, inline code:

000007FE8E8E0A20  sub         rsp,28h  
000007FE8E8E0A24  rol         qword ptr [rdx],1  

net472, aggressive inlining:

000007FE8E8E09B0  sub         rsp,28h  
000007FE8E8E09B4  mov         qword ptr [rsp+30h],rcx  
000007FE8E8E09B9  mov         ecx,r9d  
000007FE8E8E09BC  rol         qword ptr [rdx],cl

net5.0, inline code:

000007FE67E56040  push        rbp  
000007FE67E56041  sub         rsp,30h  
000007FE67E56045  lea         rbp,[rsp+30h]  
000007FE67E5604A  xor         eax,eax  
000007FE67E5604C  mov         qword ptr [rbp-8],rax  
000007FE67E56050  mov         qword ptr [rbp+10h],rcx  
000007FE67E56054  mov         qword ptr [rbp+18h],rdx  
000007FE67E56058  mov         qword ptr [rbp+20h],r8  
000007FE67E5605C  mov         dword ptr [rbp+28h],r9d  
000007FE67E56060  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp+18h]  
000007FE67E56064  rol         qword ptr [rcx],1  

net5.0, agressive inlining:

000007FE67E55B30  push        rbp  
000007FE67E55B31  sub         rsp,30h  
000007FE67E55B35  lea         rbp,[rsp+30h]  
000007FE67E55B3A  xor         eax,eax  
000007FE67E55B3C  mov         qword ptr [rbp-8],rax  
000007FE67E55B40  mov         qword ptr [rbp+10h],rcx  
000007FE67E55B44  mov         qword ptr [rbp+18h],rdx  
000007FE67E55B48  mov         qword ptr [rbp+20h],r8  
000007FE67E55B4C  mov         dword ptr [rbp+28h],r9d  
000007FE67E55B50  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp+10h]  
000007FE67E55B54  mov         rdx,qword ptr [rbp+18h]  
000007FE67E55B58  mov         r8d,dword ptr [rbp+28h]  
000007FE67E55B5C  call        CLRStub[MethodDescPrestub]@7fe67e55558 (07FE67E55558h)  


000007FE67E56010  push        rbp  
000007FE67E56011  mov         rbp,rsp  
000007FE67E56014  mov         qword ptr [rbp+10h],rcx  
000007FE67E56018  mov         qword ptr [rbp+18h],rdx  
000007FE67E5601C  mov         dword ptr [rbp+20h],r8d  
000007FE67E56020  mov         ecx,dword ptr [rbp+20h]  
000007FE67E56023  mov         rax,qword ptr [rbp+18h]  
000007FE67E56027  rol         qword ptr [rax],cl  
000007FE67E5602A  pop         rbp  
000007FE67E5602B  ret
```

Why don't they all generate the same code, i.e. the 2 instruction version in the first sample?  Is there a way to put "Rotate" in a function instead of having to inline it?

EDIT: I found a bug in the RotateLeft code I posted, it improved the generate assembly quite a bit, but it still has issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions `Hash_Inline` and `Hash_FunctionCall` are not equivalent:

- The first statement in `Hash_Inline` rotates by 1, but in `Hash_FunctionCall` it rotates by `curIndex`.
- For `RotateLeft` you may have probably meant:

```cs
private void RotateLeft(ref ulong hash, int by)
{
    hash = (hash << by) | (hash >> (hashSize - by));
}
```

(NOTE: This question has been edited to fix this issue)

If you fix these two things, the JIT compiler generates identical native code for both functions on .NET 5 (but not .NET Framework): See the disassembly [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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).

Also, if you are using .NET Core 3.0 or later and you want the disassembly of the fully optimized code, you need to call the function a sufficiently large number of times (to trigger a [tier 1 compilation](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/tiered-compilation-preview-in-net-core-2-1/)) before you get the disassembly, or use `MethodImplOptions.AggressiveOptimization`.

Comment: I actually noticed this issue right before you posted this, and was busy fixing my question when you posted your reply.  It still has issues even with the code fixed.

Comment: What did you use to get the disassembly of the JIT generated code? The RotateLeft function is being inlined in .NET 5 according to the SharpLab link that I have posted.

Comment: I compile it in Visual Studio 2019, I put a breakpoint at the beginning of each method (with Just My Code turned off), and then when it hits the breakpoint, I open the Disassembly window.

Comment: Added note about tiered compilation, see if it resolves your problem.

Comment: I ran it in a loop a million times, that wasn't enough to trigger tier 1 compilation.  But putting AggressiveOptimization on the 2 methods was sufficient to cause it to compile down to a simple "rol qword ptr [rdx],1"