Accessing pointer fields through properties
Is it possible to avoid overhead of property-method call in this case (somehow forcing compiler inline? I know this more like an Alias but there is no such thing in C#):
unsafe public static class Results
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        var cstruct = new CStruct();
        var obj     = new WrapperForCStruct(&cstruct);
        var x       = obj.Field;
        var y       = obj.ptr->field;
    }
}

public struct CStruct
{
    public int field;
}

unsafe public sealed class WrapperForCStruct(CStruct* pointer)
{
    public CStruct* ptr = pointer;

    public int Field => ptr->field;
}

Accessing obj.Field has overhead comparing to obj.ptr->field:
IL (sharplab)
var x = obj.Field;
IL_0010: dup
IL_0011: callvirt instance int32 WrapperForCStruct::get_Field()
IL_0016: pop

var y = obj.ptr->field;
IL_0017: ldfld valuetype CStruct* WrapperForCStruct::ptr
IL_001c: ldobj CStruct
IL_0021: pop

Disassembly (Release - Optimized)
var x = obj.Field;
00007FFDB5C43E96  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp-10h]  
00007FFDB5C43E9A  cmp         dword ptr [rcx],ecx  
00007FFDB5C43E9C  call        qword ptr [CLRStub[MethodDescPrestub]@00007FFDB5E4D5F0 (07FFDB5E4D5F0h)]  
00007FFDB5C43EA2  mov         dword ptr [rbp-14h],eax  
00007FFDB5C43EA5  nop  

var y = obj.ptr->field;
00007FFDB4223E97  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp-10h]  
00007FFDB4223E9B  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rcx+8]  
00007FFDB4223E9F  cmp         byte ptr [rcx],cl  


Hmm even MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining doesn't seem to work. Why are you using raw pointers anyway?

Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/67992184/1086121?

can't really reproduce on sharplab

@Charlieface This is coming from unmanaged C

@canton7 I'm talking about properties not methods

@IvanPetrov I've updated to be compatible with sharplab

To be clear: is the real thing here that you're receiving a CStruct* from the unmanaged layer, and you don't want to have to use unsafe code everywhere? Because a good option here might be to coerce the unmanaged pointer to a managed pointer when working with it, rather than using a wrapper object (entirely legit to do, but can only be held on the stack - not as a field). Alternatively, you could try using a flyweight struct that just holds a CStruct* rather than a class, so you avoid the virtcall etc

The more I think about it: the first thing I'd do here is replace unsafe public sealed class WrapperForCStruct with unsafe public readonly struct WrapperForCStruct; I suspect that might help quite a bit. I might also make the ptr private rather than public (and readonly, obvs)

@SuRGeoNix Property accessors are methods...

@canton7 They do not accept MethodImplOptions

@MarcGravell I do need a wrapper class. And even if your idea with struct is good the property will still not be inline :( However, you indeed get rid of callvirt which becomes call instance (not sure what is the difference)

They do support MethodImpl if you use a normal get rather than an expression-bodied property. But yeah, why not just use normal PInvoke rather than messing with unsafe pointers?

@Charlieface You are right, I tried to pass it to the property. By passing it to get works but actually compiler ignores it (no surprises here). By the way this struct pointers are coming from PInvokes to C functions

So you are using a heap-allocated class and a finalizer, both of which have much more severe performance penalties than a little call in the JIT Assembler. Sorry I really don't get the whole point of this question, why are you so bothered about the call? And if you are using PInvoke, how about you show that because it sounds like you are overcomplicating it in the name of mythical performance issues that you think you have.

@Charlieface The pointer struct that I receive from PInvokes is allocated (malloc) by C code and I'm responsible to free it from C#. Each structure can have a lot of fields, so each time that you try to access one of them you will get the extra overhead, which believe me, at the end is a lot because it happens on hot paths and for each field. The finalizer is a requirement as you need to dispose it. Also if you normally use the Dispose you will not have 'more severe' performance penalties.

I'd actually do managed pointers in this case and have the WrapperForCStruct as ref struct. That way we can have a ref field instead of the property. With the mouthful readonly modifiers we have a "getter".
struct CStruct {
    public int field;
}

ref struct WrapperForCStruct {
    public readonly ref readonly int Field;
    public WrapperForCStruct(ref CStruct cstruct) {
        Field = ref cstruct.field;
    }
}


In any scenario where ref struct would be usable, all you're doing here is adding overhead and indirection - it would have been far preferable to simply use ref CStruct managedPtr = ref Unsafe.AsRef<CStruct>(unmanagedPtr); and just access managedPtr.field directly, without the wrapper and without any further unsafe code

That is a nice solution however even if it does not have any more overhead during usage (as @MarcGravell mention) I would prefer to have a class instead of ref struct, especially when you plan to expose this as an API. I'm afraid that is not possible with class and might worth requesting a new C# language feature for that.

@SuRGeoNix why are you thinking class here? you're wrapping a single field, without polymorphism (sealed); this screams struct to me; the only possible reason I can think of preferring class here is if you plan on using a finalizer (~WrapperForCStruct) for cleanup - struct is actually pretty rarely used and niche, but it fits perfectly here

@MarcGravell I do indeed require disposal/finalizer for unmanaged pointer

@SuRGeoNix You can still declare a void Dispose() method on the struct and then put it in a using to dispose, it will just work. Anyway you should probably be using SafeHandle if you want to use a class rather than a struct.

@Charlieface But if the user forget to call it, you going to have memory leaks. I'm not using SafeHandle as by having a quick look, was too complex and I think it does not fit to unmanaged C. Probably is mainly for COM handles/objects. Using custom finalizer is simpler.
